# javascript array push giving different length

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting weird length value when using `array` `push` in `javascript` code in `angular` environment

```
userData:any[]=[];

loadData():any[]{
    this.userData.push({name:"name1",email:"email1"});
    this.userData.push({name:"name2",email:"email2"});
    console.log("! "+this.userData.length);
  return this.userData;
  }
```

`loadData` is called from its corresponding component.html file:

```
<p>one works!</p>
<u *ngFor="let user of loadData()">
    <li>{{user.name}}</li>
</u>
```

[image]

I was expecting output to be 2. Is there a kind of lifecycle happening here?

Also when I replace the `loadData` function with following, everything works fine. Length comes out to be 2. Like this:

```
 loadData():any[]{
  //   this.userData.push({name:"name1",email:"email1"});
  //   this.userData.push({name:"name2",email:"email2"});
  //   console.log("! "+this.userData.length);
  // return this.userData;
  let userData2 = [{name:"name1",email:"email1"},{name:"name2",email:"email2"}];
  console.log(userData2.length);
return userData2;  
}
```

I crossed checked without angular, and `push` method is giving me array length as 2 there. I am confused with this `ngFor` behavior with `push` method.

Comment: Sounds like `loadData` is called multiple times

Comment: Where is `loadData` called? Presumably in some lifecycle event which is raised multiple times ...

Comment: @derpirscher and CertainPerformance, I have tried testing with some raw array. Added some more code to illustrate my problem with push method of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is currently pushing 2 **additional** objects into your array every time you call `loadData()`

```
loadData()
console.log(this.userData.length) // 2

loadData()
console.log(this.userData.length) // 4

loadData()
console.log(this.userData.length) // 6
```

If you want to initialise some test data in an array by running a function, in order to be able to reuse this function, make sure you are either:

- Assigning the data to your variable (instead of calling `.push()`)

```
loadData(): any[] {
  this.userData = [
    {
      name: "name1",
      email: "email1"
    },
    {
      name: "name2",
      email: "email2"
    }
  ]
}

loadData()
console.log(this.userData.length) // 2

loadData()
console.log(this.userData.length) // 2
```

- If you want to use `.push()`, make sure you reset your variable before pushing

```
loadData(): any[] {
  this.userData = [];
  this.userData.push({
    name: "name1",
    email: "email1"
  });
  this.userData.push({
    name: "name2",
    email: "email2"
  });
}

loadData()
console.log(this.userData.length) // 2

loadData()
console.log(this.userData.length) // 2
```

Comment: wow! resetting the `userData` solved problem.. Yeah I was merely testing my code. But still confused. It was called from `ngFor` .. how is it possible that it is called multiple times and regular raw array does not have any such problem.